# Do we have any Spark connector to read the file(s) from OneDrive?

Tags: apache-spark, onedrive, office365connectors

Do we have any Spark connector to read the file(s) from OneDrive? Requirement is to read the file which is in Onedrive to a spark context and apply some transformations to it.